# Update button won't update data on DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
try
{
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString =
    "Dsn=mdc;" +
    "Uid=root;" +
    "Pwd=;";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tbl_delivery SET Address = @Address, AssetNumber = @AssetNumber, Contact = @Contact, DRNumber = @DRNumber, InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber, ItemQty = @ItemQty, PONumber = @PONumber, ReceivedBy = @ReceivedBy, Supplier = @Supplier WHERE No = @No;", conn);

    //DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No", noTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssetNumber", assetNumberTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", contactTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DRNumber", dRNumberTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNumber", invoiceNumberTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemQty", itemQtyTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONumber", pONumberTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReceivedBy", receivedByTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", supplierTextBox.Text);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OdbcDataAdapter ds = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds.SelectCommand = cmd;
    System.Data.DataTable dtable = new System.Data.DataTable();
    ds.Fill(dtable);
    tbl_deliveryDataGridView.DataSource = dtable;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("update successful");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Whenever I click one data from datagridview and changed it using textbox, it won't update.

Comment: does it update on the Database ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to fill your DataTable with OdbcDataAdapter and update command.

EDIT:

Here are cuts from your code:

```
//here your cmd is set to UPDATE
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tbl_delivery SET Address = @Address, AssetNumber = @AssetNumber, Contact = @Contact, DRNumber = @DRNumber, InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber, ItemQty = @ItemQty, PONumber = @PONumber, ReceivedBy = @ReceivedBy, Supplier = @Supplier WHERE No = @No;", conn);

//here your SelectCommand is set to UPDATE
ds.SelectCommand = cmd; 

//here you fill your datatable
ds.Fill(dtable);
```

You should set your SelectCommand and UpdateCommand correctly. You cannot fill datatable with UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

If your query gives the expected result, and the data get updated in then database. then you need to `ReBind` the grid to load the updated data to the grid.

let `Gv_delivery` be your datagrid then the code will be like the following:

```
Gv_delivery.Rebind
```

the code to be attached to your code after the update execute.

Comment: your table name is `tbl_delivery` so i assume the name for the grid may `Gv_delivery`. you can use the name of your grid instead for this.

Comment: i clearly mentioned it with the question. you should add the statement after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`